# FullText Search priory

Tags: sql, full-text-search

i want to use full text search for create simple search engin.

for example when user search "Hamed Khatami",search engine fetch rows that have both word then

fetch rows that have one of them.

i created bottom query

```
select * from dbo.DownloadCenterFileLanguage

where CONTAINS(*,N' "*PC*" and "*Game*" ')

UNION

select * row from dbo.DownloadCenterFileLanguage

where CONTAINS(*,N' "*PC*" or "*Game*" ')
```

but it has a problem , it order result base on P.K.

Appreciate to help me.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a day , i understand that my approach is wrong.

look at these codes

```
select * from dbo.DownloadCenterFileLanguage
inner join
CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.DownloadCenterFileLanguage,
   *, 'ISABOUT ( "hamed" , "khatami" ,"*hamed*", "*khatami*"')') AS KEY_TBL
ON DownloadCenterFileLanguage.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

with this approach everything work correctly

Best Regards